# Finding the inverse of a Rational Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$f(x)=\frac { x }{ x+4 } $$

I am not sure how to go about solving this but here is what I have done so far:

$$y=\frac { x }{ x+4 } $$

$$(x+4)y=\frac { x }{ x+4 } (x+4)$$

$$yx+4y=x$$

I feel stuck now. Where do I go from here?

Comment: $$4y=x-yx$$
$$4y=(1-y)x$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=\frac { x }{ x+4 },x\neq-4 $$
$$y(x+4)=x$$
$$xy+4y=x$$
$$xy-x=-4y$$
$$x(y-1)=-4y,y\neq1$$
$$x=\frac{-4y}{y-1}$$
$$x=\frac{4y}{1-y}$$

Comment: Wouldn't I have to interchange $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 2):

Bring the terms containing $x$ together, factor out the $x$, then divide through:
\begin{align*}
yx - x &= -4y \\
x(y - 1) &= -4y \\
x &= \frac{-4y}{y - 1}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$$y=f(x)=\frac x{x+4}$$

$$\implies f^{-1}(y)=x$$

Now $y=\dfrac x{x+4}$

Assuming $x+4\ne0, 4y+xy=x\iff x=\dfrac{4y}{1-y}$

Equate the values of $x$